# Questions about tensor products

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I've read some materials about tensor product,but there are things still confusing to me. Briefly speaking, I still wonder about the elements in a tensor product.

(1) How can we prove that some elements in tensor product are not equal?

For example, how to prove $3 \otimes \overline{2} \ne 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x] \otimes \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$? How about more complicated elements? Such as $3x \otimes \overline{4} + x^5 \otimes \overline{3} \ne 0$ although I believe it's not zero because I can't reduce it to $0$.

(2)How can we proof the right-exactness of tensor product directly?

I've been tried to proof the right-exactness of tensor product,but always get confused when dealing with specific elements of them. Is there a proof without using the "adjoint with $\rm Hom$" method?

Comment: To prove $a\otimes b\ne 0$ in $A\otimes B$, find some bilinear $f:A\times B\to C$ with $f(a,b)\ne0$.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a well known necessary and sufficient condition for the vanishing of a tensor. Search for the key word "vanten" (for vanishing tensors) in [this text](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/Atiyah_MacDonald_b/).